# Issues with Login session

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a slight problem in my login: all the validation works but on submit, the page goes blank (with url: login.php) instead of the supposed index.php-similar to the screenshot below
Here is my code and screenshot:

```
<?php
logged_in_redirect();  //to prevent access from user already logged in

//when Line 2 is un-commented it displays the following error message:"Fatal error: Call to undefined function logged_in_redirect() in /www/htdocs/w00f3b5f/kari/SAMS/login.php on line 2”

include 'core/init.php';

if(empty($_POST) === false) {
    $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($email_address) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter an email and password’;

   } else if (email_exists($email_address) === false) { //edit to suit my system
        $errors[] = 'This email address cannot be found. Have you registered?’;

    } else if (user_active($email_address) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Your account has not been activated!’;

    } else  {
        //validate email_address and password
        $login = login($email_address, $password);

        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'The email address/password combination is incorrect’;

        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login; //login returns the user id
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }   
    }   
} else {
    $errors[] = 'No data received';  
}
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if(empty($errors) === false) {
?>
    <h2>We tried to log you in, but ...</h2>
<?php
    echo output_errors($errors);
} 

include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

The screen shot below is as a result of removing the exit() from the redirection, I know this should not be done. I really don not know where the source of the error.
P.S: the greeting should have been “Hello, [first name]! but it does not display first name of the logged in user.

[image: sample screenshot]

Comment: You do have a few slanted commas " ’ " (As opposed to regular commas " ' "). Not sure if it would give you that error. Just making sure but the user does have a first name assigned to it yes? Also can I see the code for the sidebar?

Comment: @amethystdragon: I am not sure why it displays as a slanted comma, its all regular commas like: " ’ “ (as u wrote).

Answer (score 0):

```
$errors[] = 'You need to enter an email and password’;
                                               this ^
```

and

```
$errors[] = 'Your account has not been activated!’;
                                            this ^
```

will be your problem, replace them with `'`.

Comment: I am not sure why it displays as a slanted comma, its all regular straight commas (as u wrote).